# How to send emoji from android to iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, utf-8, emoji

I m creating the chatting application.Now,I m using php web-service to send and retrieve the data.Now,i m facing problem while sending emoji from android to iphone.When i sent the smiley emoji,it's dispalyed in iphone as  %Fo%9F%98%Fo%9F%98%Fo%9F%98.

I also converted in UTF8String.

```
    NSMutableArray *arrreceiveMsg= [result objectForKey:@"newMessages"];

    if ([arrreceiveMsg count] > 0)
    {
        arrreceiveMsg = [ShareOBJ filterArray:arrreceiveMsg WithClass:[Messages class]];

        [arrreceiveMsg enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Messages *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            obj.status = [NSNumber numberWithInt:Success];
           obj.message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",[obj.message UTF8String]];

            [obj updateInDB];
        }];
```

Comment: try to send in base64 of emoji and decode it on iPhone side.

Comment: @Bhupesh This is the code where i used the base64

Comment: [Base64 initialize];
NSData * data = [Base64 decode:obj.message];obj.message = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: but i m getting the null value

Comment: does android app is sending you in base64 ?

Comment: no,i m getting in utf8..I m facing this issue from last 2 days

Comment: android app is sending me in UTF8

Comment: tell the android developer to send the text in base 64. and at your end you decode it. same mechanism you have do at your end. you need to send base64 and they need to decode. by doing this you will not face any issue regarding emoji or special characters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60222/discussion-between-sweeta-and-bhupesh).

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
 NSData *data = [aStrMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
 NSString *goodValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 //this one is for sending msg

 NSData *data = [[aDictChat objectForKey:@"chat_message"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSString *aStrChatMsg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
//this one is for display msg in cell
```